# Menu does not display (dropdown) on click

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a drop-down menu that is rendered in HTML/bootstrap as follows (generated by ASP.NET MVC):

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       href="#"
       role="button"
       data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
       id="nav-dropdown"
       aria-expanded="false">
        Shop
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Cheese%20cakes">
                    Cheese cakes
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Fruit%20pies">
                    Fruit pies
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Seasonal%20pies">
                    Seasonal pies
                </a>
            </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List">All pies</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

But when I click on the word "Shop" in the rendered page, the menu does not drop down. Why not?

Comment: You have data attributes for both Bootstrap 4 and 5. That makes me wonder what you're actually loading.

Comment: @isherwood This is code from an online class. The class was created using Bootstrap 4 but I'm following it now and installed Bootstrap 5. That might be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure you are using `bootstrap.bundle` as your javascript file, and it works correctly. Please see code snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-Ez0cGzNzHR1tYAv56860NLspgUGuQw16GiOOp/I2LuTmpSK9xDXlgJz3XN4cnpXWDmkNBKXR/VDMTCnAaEooxA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       href="#"
       role="button"
       data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
       id="nav-dropdown"
       aria-expanded="false">
        Shop
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Cheese%20cakes">
                    Cheese cakes
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Fruit%20pies">
                    Fruit pies
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List?category=Seasonal%20pies">
                    Seasonal pies
                </a>
            </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pie/List">All pies</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-sH8JPhKJUeA9PWk3eOcOl8U+lfZTgtBXD41q6cO/slwxGHCxKcW45K4oPCUhHG7NMB4mbKEddVmPuTXtpbCbFA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I am creating this from a class which uses Bootstrap 4 while I am using Bootstrap 5. The class does have me include the script "~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" but no Bootstrap css file. Is this something new I need to explicitly add under Bootstrap 5?

And if so, should I pull it directly from cloudflare or can I use VisualStudio to add it as a client library where it pulls a copy down? 

Also, I added the link you gave me above to bootstrap.min.css and it still does not show. Put it both first and last of all the links in the <head>. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @DavidThielen `bootstrap.js` is not the same as `bootstrap.bundle.js`, for this to work, you need `bootstrap.bundle.js`, this is specific to bootstrap 5, [bootstrap5-introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), as stated in the comments, you are mixing version 4 with version 5 which has breaking changes. I imagine you can add this via Visual Studio using `LibMan` - [LibMan](https://www.yogihosting.com/install-bootstrap-aspnet-core/)